# Create workbook and copy sheets with values only

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub values_dump()
Dim sourceWB As Workbook
Dim destWB As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim path As String
Dim fname As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\_bck\"
fname = "values_" & Format(Now, "dd_mmm_yy_hh_mm_ss") & ".xlsm"

Set sourceWB = ThisWorkbook

Set destWB = Workbooks.Add
destWB.SaveAs path & fname

For Each ws In sourceWB.Worksheets

Workbooks(sourceWB).Sheets(ws).Copy after:=Workbooks(destWB).Sheets(1)

Next ws

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I am getting an error on this line `destWB.SaveAs path & fname` - it says that I cannot use the ".xlsm" extension ?

In addition I would like to copy the sheets to the new workbook but only retain the values and original formatting.

My code, erroneously copies all the formulae. I do not want to destruct in any way the original workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are arbitrarily tacking on a Macro-Enabled Workbook file extension (e.g. xlsm) but using [Workbook.SaveAs method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) with the default **FileFormat** paramter (found in Excel Options ► Save ► Save files in this format:. In fact, it would be better to leave off the .xlsm altogether and specify the desired file format. Excel will add .xlsm if you pick the correct format. See [xlFileFormat enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx) for a full list of available SaveAs file types.

If you want to revert the formulas to their values, simply make a copy of the worksheet then use `.Cells = .Cells.Value`.

```
Sub values_dump()
    Dim sourceWB As Workbook
    Dim destWB As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim path As String
    Dim fname As String
    Dim c As long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\_bck\"
    fname = "values_" & Format(Now, "dd_mmm_yy_hh_mm_ss") & ".xlsm"

    Set sourceWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set destWB = Workbooks.Add
    destWB.SaveAs Filename:=path & fname, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled 'Open XML Workbook Macro Enabled (52)

    For Each ws In sourceWB.Worksheets

        if ws.autofiltermode then ws.autofiltermode = false
        ws.Copy after:=destWB.Sheets(1)
        With destWB.Sheets(2).usedrange
            for c = 1 to .columns.count
                .columns(c).Cells = .columns(c).Cells.Value
            next c
        End With
        destWB.save

    Next ws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

When you **Set** a workbook-type var to a [Workbook Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835568.aspx), you can use the var directly. You seemed to be using it like it was the [Workbook.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195422.aspx). The same goes for the [Worksheet Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194464.aspx) and the Worksheet [.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196974.aspx).

Comment: thanks but I need to modify this, as I am getting out of memory error on   .Cells = .Cells.Value - if I omit this statement it works with no problems :)

Comment: I've modified the code to revert the formulas one column as a time and save the workbook between worksheet additions. If this is going to be particularly large, you may also want to change to the .SaveAs to an .xlsb Binary workbook (`FileFormat:=xlExcel12`).

Comment: ok I agree... the last problem is that the original order of the sheets is not maintained.. maybe somehow we could start copying in reverse order ?

Comment: No, it was because you were always adding the copied worksheets `after:=destWB.Sheets(1)`. They should have been added `after:=destWB.Sheets(destWB.Sheets.Count)` and then one more adjustment to `With destWB.Sheets(destWB.Sheets.Count).usedrange`. Can you make those mods?

Comment: There is a bug with copying sheets where there is an autofilter active. Any chance we can remove the filter and then re-apply it on the copied sheet?

Comment: I've added some `ws.autofiltermode` detection to turn off any active filter(s).